# Signing an iOS app with another certificate

Tags: ios, mobile, certificate, code-signing-certificate

I currently have my app deployed on the Apple Store and I had to create a new certificate for some reasons.

Now, I need to update my app on the store but I had to sign it with my new certificate.

My question is, if I sign my application with a different certificate, will the app store update the existing one on my phone or consider the application like a new application ?

Plus, if it updates the application, will my data stored in the local storage be kept ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign with another certificate. Think of company with multiple developers: they can have multiple appStore certificates.

The data stored in local storage will be kept as long as the bundle identifier stays the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As long as I don't touch the app id the apple store should update my existing app right ? Is there a way to test if it work correctly ?

Comment: No way to test directly with the appStore. But you can try to test via testFlight, the beta service from the appStore.